# int object is not iterable after entering the number of first input

Tags: python

```
             amisura = int(input("Quante volte hai misurato?:  "))
    for i in range(amisura):
     misure = input("Inserisci la misura: ")
     print("La tua media è:", sum(i)/amisura)
```

After entering the number of  first input " misure = input" , it give me this error: int object is not iterable

Comment: Well, what did you expect `sum(i)` to do?

Comment: You need to accumulate the numbers into a list, converting them into numbers in the process. Only when you have a list of numbers, use the `sum` function once (not in the loop). Alternatively, keep a running total, which is initialized to `0` and updated in each pass through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the questions in your code. Do you mean like this?

```
amisura = int(input("Quante volte hai misurato?:  "))
summ = 0
for i in range(amisura):
    misure = int(input("Inserisci la misura: "))
    summ = misure + summ
print("La tua media è:", summ/amisura)
```

Output:

```
Quante volte hai misurato?:  4
Inserisci la misura: 1
Inserisci la misura: 2
Inserisci la misura: 3
Inserisci la misura: 4
La tua media è: 2.5
```

Comment: Could you please show us the example of input and the expected output? Or do you mean the input type should be `float`? If yes, then change `int` with `float`

Comment: solved thanks `numero_misure = int ( input ("Numero misure: ") )

letture = 0.0
for i in range ( numero_misure ):
    letture += float ( input ("Lettura: ") )

print ( letture / numero_misure )`